# How to connect KairosDB with Azure Cosmos (Cassandra)

Tags: azure

I use [KairosDB](https://kairosdb.github.io/) on top of Cassandra for saving all our time series data. I am now trying to replicate the same KairosDB with Azure CosmosDB (Cassandra API). But its throwing error:

```
16:59:08.364 [main] INFO  [LZ4Compressor.java:52] - Using LZ4Factory:JNI
16:59:08.441 [main] INFO  [NettyUtil.java:73] - Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
16:59:08.842 [main] ERROR [CassandraModule.java:136] - Unable to setup cassandra schema
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host ilenstsdb2.cassandra.cosmos.azure.com/40.65.106.154:10350: Cql request had unsupported headers Compression
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$8.apply(Connection.java:392)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$8.apply(Connection.java:361)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sA6l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a huge amount of exposure to the Cassandra API but the error is indicating that your API request contained the header **Compression** while authenticating and the server didn't like it.

Make sure you're not using withCompression() when starting your datastax driver:

```
cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoint("X.X.X.X")
    .withCompression(ProtocolOptions.Compression.LZ4)
    .build();
```

...should be...

```
cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoint("X.X.X.X")
    .build();
```